# Alternatives for creating vba userforms in Excel for Mac? Can we run a macro on 365 online?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, userform, excel-365

I own Mac computer products and I use Office 365 for Mac/online. Eight years ago, I designed an Excel macro with vba userform (calculates personal financial stuff). I need to update the macro annually but haven't been able to redesign the userform. Questions...

1. Has anyone figured out how to redesign the userform within Excel for Mac without having to use a virtual machine/Windows? I would hate to pay for a vm/Windows annually just for one macro update.
2. I've noticed MS 365 does not allow any macros to run on the web versions. Have you all abandoned ship and gone a different route (ex: Google Sheets)? I would like my file to be accessible from anywhere.

Any helpful advice would be appreciated.

Comment: for online one would use office scripts: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-office-scripts-in-excel-9fbe283d-adb8-4f13-a75b-a81c6baf163a

Comment: You could make a custom UI (task panel) with script lab (TypeScript with the Office-JS library), and it'd work across all platforms, but arguably more complicated than VBA would be. Alternatively the form could be updated on Windows and still work on a Mac, or the form could be (conceivably) reimplemented as a plain old worksheet.

Comment: Thank you - I will take a look at the office scripts to see if I can get what I need working online. For the userform, I really don't have access to windows/PC's (my employer won't let us develop macros) so I would have to purchase a VM and Windows - updating it annually just for one userform. I was trying to avoid it. I may look into converting the userform to a worksheet (I believe Google Sheets does this).